# numberOfRowsInSection method is calling two times

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, xcode6

I am developing a simple table application from appcoda. I have one confusion in `numberOfRowsInSection` method. When I print the values in console using **NSLog** in `numberOfRowsInSection` method the console displays the values two times instead of one times that means the `numberOfRowsInSection` method is called two times.

So can you tell me why this is happening?

Here is my code

```
@implementation ViewController {
    NSArray *recipes;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];

}
```

This method prints the values two times in console instead of one time

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    NSLog(@"No of Recipe :- %d",[recipes count]);
    return [recipes count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"recipeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: u must have returned number of section as 2 i.e  -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{ return 2; }

Comment: Have you implement searchDisplayController with your tableview..?

Comment: [Dheeraj Singh] there is no any issue in displaying records in the table.
There are 16 rows in my table and I am returning the number of rows and print the values in console so it should be print only once i.e 
No of rows=16 
but instead it prints two time i.e 
No of rows = 16 
No of rows =16

Comment: [Seet Angel] I have not implement searchDisplayController in my tableView

Comment: The table view is allowed to send `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` to its delegate as many times as it wants. All you can be sure of is that it will call it *at least once* for each section. It is allowed to call it multiple times. Why is this a problem?

Comment: you might set two sections do check it

Comment: What is wrong if its getting printed once or twice. Why you even bother.

Comment: I am getting proper output. but I want to know why numberofRowsInSection method is calling two times

Comment: it is getting called twice. i think it may be its normal behaviour.

Comment: Its normal behaviour. when you scroll table view or reload table view its called automatically.

Comment: @Bhargav In my case also numberOfRowsInSection method is called two times automatically and I don't know why. Did you found any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It probably is a normal behaviour. Place a break point in `numberOfRows` method and have a look at the call stack. You can see that the `numberOfRows` gets called from two different flows by the framework itself. In my case, I can see that:

1. Once it gets called from `[UITableView didMoveToWindow]`
2. Other one from `[UITableView layoutSubviews]`

Comment: This is totally correct.  It is normal that iOS needs to call it - for various reasons - more than once.  Very often it will get called 3 times. It's totally normal behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

I think that You call reloadData method 2 times So numberOfRowsInSection method is also called 2 times.

Answer (score -2):

Look for the number of sections of your tableView. It must be set as 1!

Comment: I set it to 1 stil It prints the value two times i.e No. of rows = 16 and No. of rows = 16